How to bind mouse-1 and mouse-2 to seperate commands in dired?
I'm trying to make mouse-2 run dired-jump while mouse-1 runs dired-find-file.
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-2>") 'dired-jump)

(define-key dired-mode-map [mouse-1] 'dired-find-file)

The problem is that these inputs seem to get translated into one another- such that binding one prevents the other from working. So a mouse-2 event triggers find-file. I don't know why emacs does this.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Thanks to Drew, I was able to redefine mouse--click-1-maybe-follows-link so that in certain modes it is remapped to mouse-7. This allows for a cleaner solution.

(defvar mouse-1-redefine-modes '(dired-mode)
  "List of modes where mouse-1 should be remapped to mouse-7.")

(defun mouse--click-1-maybe-follows-link (&optional _prompt)
  "Turn `mouse-1' events into `mouse-2' or `mouse-7' if follows-link."
  (and mouse--last-down
       (pcase mouse-1-click-follows-link
         ('nil nil) ('double (eq 'double-mouse-1 (car-safe last-input-event)))
         (_ (and (eq 'mouse-1 (car-safe last-input-event))
                 (or (not (numberp mouse-1-click-follows-link))
                     (funcall (if (< mouse-1-click-follows-link 0)
                                  (lambda (a b) (time-less-p b a))
                                #'time-less-p)
                              (time-since (cdr mouse--last-down))
                              (/ (abs mouse-1-click-follows-link) 1000.0))))))
       (eq (car mouse--last-down)
           (event-convert-list
            `(down ,@(event-modifiers last-input-event)
                   ,(event-basic-type last-input-event))))
       (let* ((action (mouse-on-link-p (event-start last-input-event)))
              (current-mode major-mode))
         (when (and action
                    (or mouse-1-click-in-non-selected-windows
                        (eq (selected-window)
                            (posn-window (event-start last-input-event)))))
           (let ((new-event
                  (if (member current-mode mouse-1-redefine-modes)
                      'mouse-7 ; Use the symbol 'mouse-7 directly
                    (if (eq mouse-1-click-follows-link 'double)
                        'double-mouse-2 'mouse-2))))
             (if (arrayp action)
                 (vector (aref action 0))
               (progn
                 (unless (get new-event 'event-kind)
                   (put new-event 'event-kind
                        (get (car last-input-event) 'event-kind)))
                 (setf (car last-input-event) new-event)
                 (vector last-input-event))))))))



;; Define what mouse-7 does in dired mode
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<mouse-7>") 'dired-mouse-find-file)


Emacs does that because the default value of option mouse-1-click-follows-link is non-nil.  C-h v says:

mouse-1-click-follows-link is a variable defined in mouse.el.
Its value is 450
Non-nil means that clicking Mouse-1 on a link follows the link.
With the default setting, an ordinary Mouse-1 click on a link
performs the same action as Mouse-2 on that link, while a longer
Mouse-1 click (hold down the Mouse-1 button for more than 450
milliseconds) performs the original Mouse-1 binding (which
typically sets point where you click the mouse).
If value is an integer, the time elapsed between pressing and
releasing the mouse button determines whether to follow the link
or perform the normal Mouse-1 action (typically set point).
The absolute numeric value specifies the maximum duration of a
"short click" in milliseconds.  A positive value means that a
short click follows the link, and a longer click performs the
normal action.  A negative value gives the opposite behavior.
If value is double, a double click follows the link.
Otherwise, a single Mouse-1 click unconditionally follows the link.
Note that dragging the mouse never follows the link.
This feature only works in modes that specifically identify
clickable text as links, so it may not work with some external
packages.  See ‘mouse-on-link-p’ for details.
This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 22.1 of Emacs.
You can customize this variable.

If you (like I) want Mouse-1 to just set point and not ever follow links, then just customize the option to nil.
If you want it to do that only in Dired then set the buffer-local value of the variable to nil in dired-mode.
